# Using F#'s hash function inside GetHashCode() evil?

Tags: hash, f#, equality, gethashcode

I encountered a couple of places online where code looked something like this:

```
[<CustomEquality;NoComparison>]
type Test =
    | Foo
    | Bar
    override x.Equals y = 
        match y with
        | :? Test as y' ->
            match y' with
            | Foo -> false
            | Bar -> true    // silly, I know, but not the question here
        | _ -> failwith "error"   // don't do this at home

    override x.GetHashCode() = hash x
```

But when I run the above in FSI, the prompt does not return when I either call `hash foo` on an instance of `Test` or when I call `foo.GetHashCode()` directly.

```
let foo = Test.Foo;;
hash foo;;   // no returning to the console until Ctrl-break
foo.GetHashCode();;  // no return
```

I couldn't readily proof it, but it suggests that `hash x` calls `GetHashCode()` on the object, which means the above code is dangerous. Or is it just FSI playing up?

I thought code like the above just means "please implement custom equality, but leave the hash function as default".

I have meanwhile implemented this pattern differently, but am still wondering whether I am correct in assuming that `hash` just calls `GetHashCode()`, leading to an eternal loop.

---

<strike>As an aside, using equality inside FSI returns immediately, suggesting that it either does not call `GetHashCode()` prior to comparison, or it does something else.</strike> Update: this makes sense as in the example above `x.Equals` does not call `GetHashCode()`, and the equality operator calls into `Equals`, not into `GetHashCode()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not quite as simple as the `hash` function simply being a wrapper for `GetHashCode` but I can comfortably tell you that it's definitely not safe to use the implementation : `override x.GetHashCode() = hash x`.

If you trace the `hash` function through, you end up [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L1888):

```
let rec GenericHashParamObj (iec : System.Collections.IEqualityComparer) (x: obj) : int =
    match x with 
    | null -> 0 
    | (:? System.Array as a) -> 
        match a with 
        | :? (obj[]) as oa -> GenericHashObjArray iec oa 
        | :? (byte[]) as ba -> GenericHashByteArray ba 
        | :? (int[]) as ba -> GenericHashInt32Array ba 
        | :? (int64[]) as ba -> GenericHashInt64Array ba 
        | _ -> GenericHashArbArray iec a 
    | :? IStructuralEquatable as a ->    
        a.GetHashCode(iec)
    | _ -> 
        x.GetHashCode()
```

You can see here that the wild-card case calls `x.GetHashCode()`, hence it's very possible to find yourself in an infinite recursion.

The only case I can see where you might want to use `hash` inside an implementation of `GetHashCode()` would be when you are manually hashing some of an object's members to produce a hash code.

There is a (very old) example of using `hash` inside `GetHashCode()` in this way in [Don Syme's WebLog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsyme/2009/11/08/equality-and-comparison-constraints-in-f/).

---

By the way, that's not the only thing unsafe about the code you posted.

Overrides for `object.Equals` absolutely must not throw exceptions.  If the types do not match, they are to return false.  This is clearly documented in `System.Object`.

> Implementations of Equals must not throw exceptions; they should
>   always return a value. For example, if obj is null, the Equals method
>   should return false instead of throwing an ArgumentNullException.

([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1))

Comment: _"would be when you are manually hashing some of an object's members"_, yes, this actually started with creating a comparable function type, similar to `string * ('T -> 'U)`, where in the hash override I called `hash s` on the string (so, no infinite recursion there). But when I saw those threads online, I figured, hey, let's try it out... Leading to this question.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the source code. And about your comment on the exception: you are right, bad example code... I was fooling around.

Comment: @Abel Yep, I thought you probably knew this but I thought it worth putting out there for other people who view this question/answer because it's one of those common little mistakes that's quite easy to make.

Comment: You could say the same for me making `foo = bar` being _true_ and `bar = foo` being _false_, which I think would also be really bad practice ;).

Answer (score 5):

If the `GetHashCode()` method is overridden, then the [`hash` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.hash%5B%27t%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) will use that:

> [The `hash` operator is a] generic hash function, designed to return equal hash values for items that are equal according to the = operator. By default it will use structural hashing for F# union, record and tuple types, hashing the complete contents of the type. The exact behavior of the function can be adjusted on a type-by-type basis by implementing System.Object.GetHashCode for each type.

So yes, this is a bad idea and it makes sense that it would lead to an infinite loop.

Comment: _"The exact behavior of the function can be adjusted on a type-by-type basis by implementing System.Object.GetHashCode for each type."_, I noticed that too, but it doesn't say it will call `GetHashCode()`. I.e., it could be entirely reasonable to write `x.GetHashCode() = if x < 0 then 0 else hash x` (i.e., if anything below zero is to be considered equal).

Comment: Actually, I would have expected `hash` to call into `base.GetHashCode()` instead, which would _not_ lead to infinite recursion.

Comment: @Abel It says that you can change how the `hash` function behaves for a type by overriding `GetHashCode` how would its behavior change if it didn't actually call `GetHashCode()`? It sounds like you're interpreting that sentence to mean "You can use the `hash` function in overriding `GetHashCode`", which is the _opposite_ of what it says.

Comment: Not quite. I was interpreting it that it allowed special-case override, defaulting back to the original for other cases. But I see your point.